# CDH6.3 install hdfs fail

Tags: hdfs, cloudera-cdh

```
CDH6.3 install hdfs fail,  fail to format nodeName.

when commanhdfs/hdfs.sh ["format-namenode","cluster11"] 



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem with rules file {{CMF_CONF_DIR}}/redaction-rules.json
    at org.cloudera.log4j.redactor.RedactorPolicy.activateOptions(RedactorPolic`enter code here`y.java:55)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:149)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: {{CMF_CONF_DIR}}/redaction-rules.json (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:766)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2903)
    at org.cloudera.log4j.redactor.StringRedactor.createFromJsonFile(StringRedactor.java:248)
    at org.cloudera.log4j.redactor.RedactorPolicy.activateOptions(RedactorPolicy.java:52)
    ... 20 more
```

has error,i need help.thanks for the world,there has command as follow:
Sat Jun 13 13:43:29 CST 2020
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181
using /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181 as JAVA_HOME
using 6 as CDH_VERSION
using /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/37-hdfs-NAMENODE-format as CONF_DIR
using  as SECURE_USER
using  as SECURE_GROUP
CONF_DIR=/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/37-hdfs-NAMENODE-format
CMF_CONF_DIR=
unlimited

Comment: Hi 王毅松, Please put the "has command as follow:" inside a code fence (```  Sat Jun 13 13:43:29 CST 2020 JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181  ...  ```) , just like you did for the error message. That will help people understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: yum install perl

Answer (score 0):

you need to install perl first.